# Workaround to add a default parameterless constructor to a struct

Tags: c#, .net, unmanaged, il

Let me describe my problem - I have a struct that wraps an unmanaged handle (let's call it Mem). I need this handle to call a particular method (say "retain" or alternatively, maintain a reference count) whenever it is copied.

In other words, I need a struct that maintains a reference count internally (I have a mechanism externally as well, but need a way to invoke that mechanism).

Unfortunately, C# doesn't let me do this in any way.

I also cannot make Mem a class because I will pass an array of these structs to unmanaged code and I do NOT want to convert them one by one before passing them in (just pin and pass).

Does anyone know of any workaround (IL Weaving, etc) that can be applied to add this behavior in? I believe IL doesn't prevent me from doing this, only C#, correct?

I am happy to answer any questions about the framework and restrictions I have, but I am not looking for - *"please change your design"* or *"don't use C# for this"* answers, thanks very much.

Comment: Thanks to everyone who answered. I will think some more about this and see what I can come up with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Edit: I hosted the work from this answer on GitHub: the [NOpenCL library](https://github.com/sharwell/NOpenCL).**

Based on your comment, I determined the following as an appropriate long-term course of action for the problems being discussed here. Apparently the problem centers around the use of OpenCL within managed code. What you need is a proper interop layer for this API.

As an experiment, I wrote a managed wrapper for a large portion of the OpenCL API to evaluate the viability of `SafeHandle` to wrap `cl_mem`, `cl_event`, and other objects which require a call to `clRelease*` for cleanup. The most challenging part was implementing methods like `clEnqueueReadBuffer` which can take an array of these handles as a parameter. The initial declaration of this method looked like the following.

```
[DllImport(ExternDll.OpenCL)]
private static extern ErrorCode clEnqueueReadBuffer(
    CommandQueueSafeHandle commandQueue,
    BufferSafeHandle buffer,
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)] bool blockingRead,
    IntPtr offset,
    IntPtr size,
    IntPtr destination,
    uint numEventsInWaitList,
    [In, MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPArray)] EventSafeHandle[] eventWaitList,
    out EventSafeHandle @event);
```

Unfortunately, the P/Invoke layer does not support marshaling an array of `SafeHandle` objects, so I implemented an `ICustomMarshaler` called [`SafeHandleArrayMarshaler`](https://github.com/sharwell/NOpenCL/blob/master/NOpenCL/SafeHandles/SafeHandleArrayMarshaler.cs) to handle this. Note that the current implementation does not use Constrained Execution Regions, so an asynchronous exception during marshaling can cause it to leak memory.

```
internal sealed class SafeHandleArrayMarshaler : ICustomMarshaler
{
    private static readonly SafeHandleArrayMarshaler Instance = new SafeHandleArrayMarshaler();

    private SafeHandleArrayMarshaler()
    {
    }

    public static ICustomMarshaler GetInstance(string cookie)
    {
        return Instance;
    }

    public void CleanUpManagedData(object ManagedObj)
    {
        throw new NotSupportedException();
    }

    public void CleanUpNativeData(IntPtr pNativeData)
    {
        if (pNativeData == IntPtr.Zero)
            return;

        GCHandle managedHandle = GCHandle.FromIntPtr(Marshal.ReadIntPtr(pNativeData, -IntPtr.Size));
        SafeHandle[] array = (SafeHandle[])managedHandle.Target;
        managedHandle.Free();

        for (int i = 0; i < array.Length; i++)
        {
            SafeHandle current = array[i];
            if (current == null)
                continue;

            if (Marshal.ReadIntPtr(pNativeData, i * IntPtr.Size) != IntPtr.Zero)
                array[i].DangerousRelease();
        }

        Marshal.FreeHGlobal(pNativeData - IntPtr.Size);
    }

    public int GetNativeDataSize()
    {
        return IntPtr.Size;
    }

    public IntPtr MarshalManagedToNative(object ManagedObj)
    {
        if (ManagedObj == null)
            return IntPtr.Zero;

        SafeHandle[] array = (SafeHandle[])ManagedObj;
        int i = 0;
        bool success = false;
        try
        {
            for (i = 0; i < array.Length; success = false, i++)
            {
                SafeHandle current = array[i];
                if (current != null && !current.IsClosed && !current.IsInvalid)
                    current.DangerousAddRef(ref success);
            }

            IntPtr result = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(array.Length * IntPtr.Size);
            Marshal.WriteIntPtr(result, 0, GCHandle.ToIntPtr(GCHandle.Alloc(array, GCHandleType.Normal)));
            for (int j = 0; j < array.Length; j++)
            {
                SafeHandle current = array[j];
                if (current == null || current.IsClosed || current.IsInvalid)
                {
                    // the memory for this element was initialized to null by AllocHGlobal
                    continue;
                }

                Marshal.WriteIntPtr(result, (j + 1) * IntPtr.Size, current.DangerousGetHandle());
            }

            return result + IntPtr.Size;
        }
        catch
        {
            int total = success ? i + 1 : i;
            for (int j = 0; j < total; j++)
            {
                SafeHandle current = array[j];
                if (current != null)
                    current.DangerousRelease();
            }

            throw;
        }
    }

    public object MarshalNativeToManaged(IntPtr pNativeData)
    {
        throw new NotSupportedException();
    }
}
```

This allowed me to successfully use the following interop declaration.

```
[DllImport(ExternDll.OpenCL)]
private static extern ErrorCode clEnqueueReadBuffer(
    CommandQueueSafeHandle commandQueue,
    BufferSafeHandle buffer,
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)] bool blockingRead,
    IntPtr offset,
    IntPtr size,
    IntPtr destination,
    uint numEventsInWaitList,
    [In, MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.CustomMarshaler, MarshalTypeRef = typeof(SafeHandleArrayMarshaler))] EventSafeHandle[] eventWaitList,
    out EventSafeHandle @event);
```

This method is declared as private so I could expose it through a method that handles the `numEventsInWaitList` and `eventWaitList` arguments properly according to the OpenCL 1.2 API documentation.

```
internal static EventSafeHandle EnqueueReadBuffer(CommandQueueSafeHandle commandQueue, BufferSafeHandle buffer, bool blocking, IntPtr offset, IntPtr size, IntPtr destination, EventSafeHandle[] eventWaitList)
{
    if (commandQueue == null)
        throw new ArgumentNullException("commandQueue");
    if (buffer == null)
        throw new ArgumentNullException("buffer");
    if (destination == IntPtr.Zero)
        throw new ArgumentNullException("destination");

    EventSafeHandle result;
    ErrorHandler.ThrowOnFailure(clEnqueueReadBuffer(commandQueue, buffer, blocking, offset, size, destination, eventWaitList != null ? (uint)eventWaitList.Length : 0, eventWaitList != null && eventWaitList.Length > 0 ? eventWaitList : null, out result));
    return result;
}
```

The API is finally exposed to user code as the following instance method in my `ContextQueue` class.

```
public Event EnqueueReadBuffer(Buffer buffer, bool blocking, long offset, long size, IntPtr destination, params Event[] eventWaitList)
{
    EventSafeHandle[] eventHandles = null;
    if (eventWaitList != null)
        eventHandles = Array.ConvertAll(eventWaitList, @event => @event.Handle);

    EventSafeHandle handle = UnsafeNativeMethods.EnqueueReadBuffer(this.Handle, buffer.Handle, blocking, (IntPtr)offset, (IntPtr)size, destination, eventHandles);
    return new Event(handle);
}
```

Comment: Marking this as the answer because this is the correct long-term way to solve this problem. For my specific case, I ended up wrapping my Cl.Mem structure opaquely inside a PooledMem class which inherits from SafeHandle. Then, whenever the main memory Pool exhibited memory pressure I called GC.Collect(0) to collect any orphaned PooledMem objects. This had the side effect of PooledMems not being directly usable in OpenCL.Net 's API anymore but the performance and usability tradeoff highly warranted it. Thanks @280Z28!

Answer (score 5):

> I believe IL doesn't prevent me from doing this, only C#, correct?

Yes, that's right where "this" is "a parameterless constructor for a struct". I [blogged about that](http://msmvps.com/blogs/jon_skeet/archive/2008/12/10/value-types-and-parameterless-constructors.aspx) a while ago.

However, having a parameterless constructor does *not* do what you want in terms of notifying you every time a struct is copied. There's basically no way of doing that, as far as I'm aware. The constructor isn't even called in every case when you end up with a "default" value, and even if it were, it's certainly *not* called just for copy operations.

I know you don't want to hear "please change your design" but you're simply asking for something which *does not exist* in .NET.

I would suggest having some sort of method on the value type which returns a new copy, having taken appropriate action. You then need to make sure you *always* call that method at the right time. There will be *nothing* preventing you from getting this wrong, other than whatever testing you can build.

Comment: Ah, I thought that even if internally invoked, the default constructor would somehow execute. I see this is not the case. How, then - if at all can I do what I need?

Comment: @ananthonline: As I said in my answer, this is just something .NET doesn't provide. I've suggested a workaround you could use if you're *really really careful*... but basically you're going against the design of .NET, so don't expect much help. If you're *just* looking for something like reference counting then `SafeHandle` may help, but again that's a class. You could have a reference to one within your struct, of course...

Answer (score 4):

> Does anyone know of any workaround (IL Weaving, etc) that can be applied to add this behavior in? I believe IL doesn't prevent me from doing this, only C#, correct?

This is correct, somewhat.  The reason C# prevents this is that the constructor will not be used, even if its defined in IL, in many cases.  Your case is one of these - if you create an array of structs, the constructors will not be called, even if they're defined in the IL.

Unfortunately, there isn't really a workaround since the CLR won't call the constructors, even if they exist.

Comment: Thank you for your answer - please see my response to Jon's answer above.

Comment: @ananthonline Unfortunately, there isn't a workaround that I know of - any "workaround" would require a "pull" mechanism instead of a push mechanism (ie: your struct could reference a class, and manually check for values).  This is one of those cases where a class is really the way to go, but I agree, it's a killer if you need to pass in an array of them.  What are you trying to manage here?

Comment: I am managing OpenCL buffers (http://openclnet.codeplex.com). I am using large numbers of buffers in a very performance critical app, and I need to maintain a pool of these buffers. Unfortunately, unbalanced Takes and Puts on this pool easily cause instability. I was trying to mitigate that using reference counting in the struct (because I may take two buffers, say A and B. If I were to then say A = B and then Put(A), Put(B) - this is wrong. I lost the handle to A when it was copied.

Comment: @ananthonline *If* you're willing to call a method on the struct prior to assignment, you might be able to take inspiration from something like CancellationToken (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.cancellationtoken.aspx), as this is a struct, but effectively a struct holding the reference to a value type managing the "resource".  This was designed with similar design goals (easy and fast to pass), but only works in a "pull" method (ie: check prior to usage), since the runtime doesn't really support copy construction/reference counting/etc

Comment: Could you describe this in greater detail or point me to some reference that does, please?

Comment: @ananthonline Take a look at the reference source for that struct - it's tied to a CTSource class which manages the state.  Documentation for the entire process is at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd997364.aspx  Note that this isn't a direct solution in any way, shape, or form, for your issue - but I could see how you could (maybe) use it as a way to structure something you can pass around.